# Start VM as main window on boot

Tags: kvm-virtualization

How to make `qemu-kvm` to run VM on linux boot and open guest window fullscreen?

So for user is like Guest OS is only OS that installed. Guest will be Windows, and host - Linux. Also will be good to to make user has no option to switch to host os from keyboard

Comment: Why not just use ordinary thin clients, then?

Comment: Yeah! good idea!